# Setting Up SQLite3 PDO Drivers in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm working my way 'slowly' through the php101 tutorials and have got to number 9, where I need SQLite.

I've got SQLite3 running and can access via the CLI, (see screenshot of a little test DB) but when I try the tutorial scripts in php101, I get a blank browser screen. I now know this is because SQLite3 uses PDO (php101 is based on SQLite v2).

Couldn't post and image so CLI says:

SQLite version 3.7.2

Enter ".help" for instructions

Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> select * from books;

1|The Lord of the Rings|J.R. Tolkien

Etc Etc

Rather than go backwards, I'm trying to figure out how to enable the SQLite3 PDO driver (which I know is named sqlite) but those who have posted on stackoverflow to date, seems to have the SQLite driver installed and enable already, so driver config was not actually explained.

(sorry could post an image) but phpinfo for PDO says:

### PDO

### PDO support | enabled

### PDO drivers |mysql

### pdo_mysql

### PDO Driver for MySQL |enabled

### Client API version   |5.1.49

I've checked on www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO but it is not explained there either.

My System is Linux Ubuntu 10.10

Apache - version 2.2.16

PHP version 5.3.3

SQLite 3.7.2

I'm trying to get this running on localhost as a learning aid initally.

Can someone explain how to install/configure the SQLite3 driver.

Answer (score 47):

It's all easy when you know how, eventually found a post on www.news.php.net which provided a clue.

So for anyone else stuck on this, just open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

note don't put a 3 and the end just leave it as sqlite

You will have to restart your machine, if you then check phpinfo you will find an entry for 
SQLite and the drivers enabled for sqlite2 and sqlite (note sqlite is the SQLite3 driver)

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Actually, you do not need to restart the machine but only the relevant service. On Ubuntu 12, it's most likely 'service php5-fpm restart' (exact service name may vary depending on how you installed your php server).

Comment: To restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: No need to restart apache2. It will automatically do that.

`apache2_invoke php5: already enabled
 * Restarting web server apache2 `

Comment: I just tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 Mate edition, and I did have to restart Apache manually after php5-sqlite. Maybe that option depends on the OS?

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In ubuntu 16.04 there is no `php5-sqlite`

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
sudo service apache2 restart
```