# php5 missing sqlite pdo driver

Tags: php, macos, sqlite, configuration, pdo

It seems that recent versions of php (5.3 and above?) the sqlite driver for pdo is not installed/enabled by default. This, despite [official claims to the contrary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php).

Although there appears to be an [easy fix for linux/debian/ubuntu users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608863/setting-up-sqlite3-pdo-drivers-in-php) thanks to `apt-get` I'm having trouble fixing this on OSX (I think ampps works OK, but that lacks other extensions I need, and mac ports doesn't work).  Anyone have a fix for this?  (failing that, more info?)

Comment: Check here http://abouthalf.com/development/php-in-snow-leopard/

Comment: Thx @Yogus I may be able to find something in that.  That page is largely about mysql (not sqlite) however.

Comment: google is your friend [this question has been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186371/how-do-i-enable-sqlite3-in-os-x-10-5-8-with-php)

Comment: @Joe. Although I find the ubiquitous "google is your friend" comment terribly annoying (after googling this for most of the day) the link you provided was helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, its not the same question.  My question is specifically about the sqlite _pdo driver_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [macports apache2 install missing pdo drivers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975056/macports-apache2-install-missing-pdo-drivers)

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 I apologise for that google bit, I was feeling a bit snarky when I wrote that, and shouldn't have vented it on you.

Comment: I'm starting to get really annoyed with heavy handed SO 'moderators' who mess with helpful questions/answers.  Note that the question that this one is ment to be a duplicate of is specifically about macports, while this one isn't.  Also, the other question has had the answer deleted.  Non mentally challenged people might mark that one as the duplicate (leaving at least one helpful question/answer intact)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

```
sudo port install php5-sqlite
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +sqlite
```

The second line here didn't seem to do anything, but you never know.

After restarting I noticed I didn't have imagemagick, which I thought I already had, so

```
sudo port install php5-imagick
```

Now restarting apache2 the "macports" way:

```
sudo port unload apache2
sudo port load apache2
```

And looking at phpinfo, I have sqlite2 and sqlite (which, confusingly, is sqlite3) drivers enabled for pdo.

Comment: Note that this is a solution only if you are using macports, or are prepared to use it.